# scanf("%d") works correctly with character

Tags: c

The code is:

```
int main() {
    scanf("%d");
    puts("hello!");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

If I input a number like **7**, the program crashes but if I input a character like **h**, the program executes successfully.

Could you please explain me the reason behind it?
I am using MinGW on Windows XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access specified `%d` won't get other character except number.

If you give other character the scanf get executed and nothing will store.

When you give numeric character the scanf get executed and try to store the value.

Due to storage location is unavailable the program get crashed.

Try to use the storage location in the `scanf` like

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

The every version say warning to storage location.
So try to check warnings.

Answer (score 3):

1. Compile with the warnings.
2. Read the manual page you will not that `scanf("%d");` will require an address to put the number into if there is one

Try

```
int x;

scanf("%d", &x);
```

You should also check the return value from `scanf` as per the manual page. I leave that as an exercise to the reader to do with as he will.

Comment: I know that scanf requires address of a variable to save the input. I was just experimenting with it. Checking return value of the method was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   check = scanf("%c %d",&a, &b);
   printf("check = %d \n",check);
```